# VPN Server - SSH Configuration Changed

Tags: server, home-directory

I have a private VPN server I have been using for months now which also hosts some web interfaces which can only be accessed over VPN.

I don't really connect to the server with ssh much, since I usually just connect to the VPN and then that's that. However, I have just logged on via ssh for the first time in a while and some things are different. My home directory is missing folders that I had left there before (there isn't even a .ssh directory anymore, and I also had a folder containing information for an openvpn certificate authority) and ssh seems now to be configured to take passwords where I had it set up before allow logins with RSA and not accept password logins. However, I can still connect to the VPN without any issue.

My VPS host has done maintenance and rebooted the machine a few times since I last logged in, however I wouldn't expect that to have caused this. Is there any good reason why this might have happened? Could the missing .ssh directory and the change in ssh configuration be related?

Comment: Seems you've been hacked :-/

Comment: How? My machine was set up to only allow ssh via RSA. I have Fail2Ban running which bans for 30 minutes...

Comment: I can still log in with my password. So no one has changed it.

Comment: I (obviously) don't know how, but your description looks _very_ suspicious.

Comment: It could be that I am thinking of another server, but I was pretty sure that's how I had it set up.